# MP4 not playing audio on Safari

Tags: html, audio, video, safari, media

I have an video file containing a "blank" video stream and an audio track.

It plays just fine in Chrome or VLC, but in Quicktime or Safari I get only the "video" playing (as in, the slider moves to show progress, but no sound is produced).

Here's the `media-info` output for the file. Can someone figure out what's wrong with it and why it'd be an issue for Safari? My understanding is, it's simply AVC + MP3 in an MP4 container:

```
General
Complete name                            : 1_11.instrumental.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 10.9 MiB
Duration                                 : 4 min 36 s
Overall bit rate                         : 330 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf58.64.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 4 min 36 s
Bit rate                                 : 2 936 b/s
Width                                    : 64 pixels
Height                                   : 64 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.000
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.029
Stream size                              : 99.0 KiB (1%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 161 r3027 4121277
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x1:0x111 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=2 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=23.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Format settings                          : Joint stereo
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-6B
Duration                                 : 4 min 36 s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 320 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 10.5 MiB (97%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```